Request lambda authoriser not called
I have a request lambda authoriser but when making an http post request to the connection that I created, I realise that the authoriser is not called and it still asks for attaching oauthorization as you can see in the screenshot
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/v8VrhQdo.png**`strong text`**
here is my function and I need to mention that the identitysource is working fine:
const customAuthorizer = createAuthorizer(scope, "ConnectionsAuth", {
  apiId: httpApi.attrApiId,
  name: "connectionsauth",
  authorizerType: "REQUEST",
  authorizerUri:  `arn:aws:apigateway:eu-west-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${props.authorizerArn}/invocations`,
  authorizerResultTtlInSeconds: 120,    
  identitySource: ["$request.header.Authorization"],
  authorizerPayloadFormatVersion: "2.0"
}}```

```export const createAuthorizer = (scope: Construct, id: string, props: CfnAuthorizerProps) => {
return new apigateway.CfnAuthorizer(scope, id, props)

};
export declare class CfnAuthorizer extends cdk.CfnResource implements cdk.IInspectable {
    /**
     * The CloudFormation resource type name for this resource class.
     */
    static readonly CFN_RESOURCE_TYPE_NAME: string;
    /**
     * Build a CfnAuthorizer from CloudFormation properties
     * A factory method that creates a new instance of this class from an object
     * containing the CloudFormation properties of this resource.
     * Used in the @aws-cdk/cloudformation-include module.
     *


What does the createAuthorizer function do? Can you include the code?

Sure, I just edited the post

You've created the authorizer, but didn't attach it to your API method.

How to do that without using the console ? Sorry if that looks like a dump question , I am new in that and trying to learn . I don't understand what I'am missing exactly here !
